# bootstrap 4 carousel images not appearing (contains overlay)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background-image, carousel, overlay

guys am trying to make carousel with 3 background images.
when the carousel slides the other image must appear.
what's happening is that only the first image appears, but the rest will not, though instead of the background image, the background color of the slider will appear.

so I need all the background-images to appear

thank you!

HTML CODE

```
 <div class="slider">
    <div id="main-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#main-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <h1>We are an independent <br>design and <span>development</span><br> agencey.</h1>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item active"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
         .slider {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        .carousel-indicators li {
            width: 14px;
            height: 14px;
            padding: 0px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 2px solid #fff;
        }
        .carousel-indicators li:hover {
            background: #fff;
        }
        .slider .carousel-inner {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: left;
        }
        .carousel-inner h1 {
            z-index: 3;
            left: 4rem;
            color: #fff;
            line-height: 1.4;
            max-width: 800px;
            font-size: 4.2rem;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .carousel-inner h1 > span {
            padding: 0 1rem;
            background-color: #ed1d24;
        }
        .slider .overlay {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .slider .carousel-item:nth-child(1) {
            background: url(../images/slider_001.jpg) no-repeat center center;
            background-size: cover; 
        }
        .slider .carousel-item:nth-child(2) {
            background: url(../images/slider_002.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
            background-size: cover; 
        }
        .slider .carousel-item:nth-child(3) {
            background: url(../images/slider_006.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
            background-size: cover; 
        }
```

Comment: your class names in the css don't match the class names in the html...

Comment: that was the navigation bar, I edited it, now this is the HTML code for slider
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do not use **div** with **carousel-item** to use any other html element until it is calculated with the divs
you can use  for example

2) Set height **carousel-item** in css

3) Use **nth-of-type** instead of **nth-child**

`click here:` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmyVoX